# HyperVM Disk Issue

Tags: linux, centos, webserver

I have HyperVM installed on a server with a 250 GB SSD hard disk. Now, it is showing "Disk quota exceeded" error. On the same server I have a 6 TB SATA HDD. I want to move my HyperVM from SSD to SATA.

Can you please help me out with it?

Comment: Just move the vhdd file and point the virtual machine to the new location